# Fastest way to count occurrence of words in Pandas

Tags: python, string, count

I have a list of strings. I want to count the occurrence of all the words in each row of a Pandas column and add a new column with this count.

```
words = ["I", "want", "please"]
data = pd.DataFrame({"col" : ["I want to find", "the fastest way", "to 
                              count occurrence", "of words in a column", "Can you help please"]})
data["Count"] = data.col.str.count("|".join(words))
print(data)
```

The code shown here does exactly what I want, but it's taking a long time to run for a long text and long list of words. Can you suggest a faster way to do the same thing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `Counter`. If you have multiple sets of `words` to test against the same text, just save the intermediate step after applying `Counter`. As these counted words are now in a dictionary keyed on the word, it is an O(1) operation to test if this dictionary contains a given word.

```
from collections import Counter

data["Count"] = (
    data['col'].str.split()
    .apply(Counter)
    .apply(lambda counts: sum(word in counts for word in words))
)
>>> data
                    col  Count
0        I want to find      2
1       the fastest way      0
2   to count occurrence      0
3  of words in a column      0
4   Can you help please      1
```

Comment: I tested your solution and the time was divided by 4. Thanks.